# Why could the parallel code of a nested for loop using multiprocessing in python take more time than the serial code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have been trying to speed up a code in python for many days (without success), and now is impossible to run it due to its computational requirements. Basically, I want to fill an array of `1000 x 1000 x 256` elements multiples times (around 1 million times), since the matrix `Pfaces_hh11` is "evolving in time". To fill this array, the function `Flux_pos()` is used inside a nested for loops as following:

```py
    def Flux_pos(k):
        Pfaces_h  = 0

        if ( ACURV_hh[ k ] >= ADEL_hh[ k ] ):
            Pfaces_h = Ph[ k-1]
        else:
            Pfaces_h = 0.5 * ( Ph[k] + Ph[k-1] ) - 0.5*c_hh[k] * ( Ph[k] - Ph[k-1] ) - ( 1 - c_hh[k]**2)/6 * ( Ph[k] -2*Ph[k-1] + Ph[k-2] )         
 
        if ( DEL_hh[k] > 0 ):
            
            if ( Pfaces_h <= Ph[k-1] ):
                Pfaces_h = Ph[k-1]
            elif ( Pfaces_h >= min( phi_ref_hh[k], Ph[k] ) ):
                Pfaces_h = min( phi_ref_hh[k], Ph[k] )

        elif ( DEL_hh[k] < 0 ):
            
            if ( Pfaces_h >= Ph[k-1] ):
                Pfaces_h = Ph[k-1]
            elif ( Pfaces_h <= max( phi_ref_hh[k], Ph[k] ) ):
                Pfaces_h = max( phi_ref_hh[k], Ph[k] )

    return Pfaces_h
```

Where `ACURV_hh`, `ADEL_hh`, `Ph`, `c_hh`, `DEL_hh` and `phi_ref_hh` are global variables. Then I called the function `Flux_pos()` to fill the array `Pfaces_hh11` in the main code:

```py
        for time in range(0, N):
            
            #some calculations 1#

            for i in range(2, 998):      
                for j in range(2, 998):
                    for k in range(2, 254):
                        Pfaces_hh11[i,j,k] = Flux_pos(k)       

            #some calculations 1#
```

To parallelize this part, I tried the following:

```py
          for time in range(0, N):
            
            #some calculations 1#

            for i in range(2, 998):      
                for j in range(2, 998):

                    if __name__ == "__main__":                
                    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=6)    
                    result = p.map(Flux_pos, range(2, 254))

            #some calculations 2#
```

However, when I run the code, the parallel version takes even more time than the serial one. I really appreciate any comment and recommendations, since I am new to python.

I don't know if this is useful, but I have an iMac with a 3 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i5.

Comment: You are talking about calling your `flux_pos` function 256 quadrillion times.  That's going to take many years to run.  Now, one might note that you are actually making a million copies of your 256 entry plane; it would be quicker to copy that rather than call the function so many times..

Comment: `multiprocessing` is not useful on a microscopic scale like that.  Every call creates a brand new process, which has to load the Python interpreter and reload all of your modules before it can even start running your code.

Comment: Instead of spawning a new process for each piece of work, you should make use of your computer's processing power by spawning worker processes once and then passing the details about the work to them - it'll require some careful design decisions, more so if you're looking to aggregate all the results in a single accessible place. Not a trivial problem.

Comment: `flux_pos` has about 20 additions, 5 multiplications, and an exponentiation.  Say it's 30 operations, 256M times is 80 billion operations.  On a 3GHz CPU, that's about 30 seconds for each i/j/k loop, and that's not counting the Python interpreter overhead.  You need to consider doing this in C or C++ with some GPU assistance.

Comment: Can you use Numpy to do this?  I can't quite tell what your data is, but if it numeric which it seems to be from the "flux" variable name, I would try to vectorize your operators using Numpy.

Comment: Based on the code you provided, `Flux_pos()` only depends on `k`. Why is it being recalculated for each `i` and `j`? If that is correct, move `k` to the outermost loop, calculate `Flux_pos(k)` once for each 'k' and the inner loops merely copies it for each value of `i` and `j`.  That should get you a significant speed up.